# Root access permission in normal user directories?

Tags: linux, permissions, file-permissions

Short story; I run a setup as `root` to install a program, which will create some files and directories in home folder of a normal user.

The error is I don't have write permission to it. So I go to the destination folder, and run `chmod a+rw *`, this should be enough.

Result of `ll`:

```
total 4
drwxrwxrwx 3 db db 4096 Nov 23 13:57 v10.5
```

So AFAIK, others have read,write,execute permission on that folder. But the program still reports that I don't have write permission (Again, I run it as `root`)

So how to fix this? Any ideas are appreciated.

PS: For a long and more detailed story; please visit **[here](https://dba.stackexchange.com/questions/83371/db2-install-do-not-have-write-permission-on-the-directory-or-file)** .

Comment: Anybody? Google ain't my friend anymore :(

Comment: You will need to provide more details of the install process. Perhaps you start the install process as root but it (quite sensibly) switches to a lower privilege user.

Comment: Yes ,the program needs `root`  to install, it creates a few users to run the program. But why a `root` program can't write to a directory of a normal user with permission like this `drwxrwxrwx`?

Comment: Although the script may run as root initially, it may switch itself to a lower privilege user (perhaps one of the ones it has just created).

Comment: Maybe you're right, but since this a program, so I can't change anything :(

Comment: No - but perhaps ask whomever (person, group, company) created the installation script for some more details. Sorry I can't be of any more help.